# Expose global variable in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, global-variables

I know exposing a global variable is not a good practice, but in my case its necessary. I have another applications on a web-page alongside my angular one and those must access one globally exposed variable.

My question is, how to expose a variable inside angular?
When I'm appending it to `document` like this: `document.test = "Hello";`, the TypeScript throws an error `Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Document'.`

Is there an another way of doing this?

Comment: It'd primarily TS and not JS question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general sense, yeah you would not want to do that if you just have an Angular app. To answer your question tho so that you can get the other part of your app to work, did you try to use a declare statement at the top of your file to prevent TypeScript from complaining?

```
// import statements

declare var document;
```

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/

Additionally, you can have the TypeScript compiler treat a known variable as the `any` type so you can use whatever properties you want on it that it may not know about. To do this, you simply cast the variable using the `as` syntax. It is better to use TypeScript's type checking, but you can opt out of it by doing this.

```
(document as any).foo = 'bar';
```

You should also be able to create an interface for these global properties and cast the document as that type to make use of TypeScript's type safety in your Angular code.

```
interface GlobalDocumentProps {
    foo: string;
}

(document as GlobalDocumentProps).foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: It still complains because he knows about document but did not about properties I try to append to the document.

Comment: Did you try something like (document as any).test?