# How to create a global function/variable (at window) in Angular for user interaction with dev tools/browser console?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

I know there are [proper approaches for defining global variables/functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43991306/5008962), but I do have one – IMHO valid – use case (maybe the only valid one for this ) for a "real" global variable directly at the JS `window` object of Angular?

### Use case

Example **user story:** I, as a power user, want to have exposed variables and functions in my `window` or `document` namespace or so I can tinker with the application in depth (if I know what they are doing™) to call functions to trigger things in the Angular app.

E.g. I may expose a function `reloadThatExampleData` to reload some data that is shown, or `sendServerMessage` to have a convenient function to send test data from the server.

I know I could obviously add buttons to the UI for this, but I do not want that, because these are "advanced features", which should be well hidden (so only "power users" can discover this).
An obvious example may e.g. also be **cheats** in a game.
The browser console is very well suited for that, it's hidden by default, needs no special implementation (I don't need to create yet another GUI for that), but for power users it's still easy enough to discover.

You could also frame it differently: I want a WebCli ("web command line interface") or browser console UI ("browser console user interface").
Note my use case also has a "debugging" idea in mind: I want "hooks" into my application (e.g. for manually sending a message etc.), so I can manually trigger some thing to test if that works, without having to (re-)write extra (debugging) functions or so. The console is also ideal for this, as it should be easy enough to export a function (instead of having to write an UI… and it has auto-completion and other nice things already built-in in most browsers).
This feature is also useful if you need to demo things in your code (as a presentation or so) and cannot/do not want to recompile everything again.

### Technically

The functions should then be able to just be from a service, e.g. Or a component, for that matter.
It may be okay, if we would need a central service for that, but it would be more elegant to be able to do that everywhere. (maybe even with an annotation like "ExportFunctionAsConsoleCheat" or so)

I have found [this question for how to [declare some variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49124410/5008962) though is still not enough to run functions even.

Comment: You could ship non-minified code and allow "power users" to write almost anything they want.

Comment: And how'd they write that in the console? I mean, of course people could recompile the project, but that's not my aim.